# Oil prices forecast methods

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, reference-request, oil, forecasting

Oil prices have a significant impact on the world economy, positive for exporters and negative for importers to oversimplify a bit.
They are also known to be highly volatile, and depend on hard to predict parameters, such as the changing policy of the OPEC which resembles a cartel.

Most international organizations (European Commission and IMF for instance), seems to use future prices.

Do you have any studies mentionning or better menchmarking oil prices forecast methods ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of literature on this question.

[This review](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2275428) looks like a good place to start although it is from 2013. It looks at a wide range of both qualitative and quantitative approaches.

> Among them, the most frequently used technique is the time series econometrics in order to forecast the
>   volatility of oil prices, the second frequently used is the financial method, the third frequently
>   used methods are based on structural models and non standard computational models, and the
>   least used technique is the qualitative knowledge based method